# Working WebView program stopped displaying the full page

Tags: webview, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX program that has been running fine for about one year.
Now, it no longer renders the full page. I have no idea how to fix this.

It is some simple code.

```
//access WebView in FXML document
@FXML
WebView MyBrowser; //mywebview is the fxid

public void displayWeb() {
    WebEngine eng = MyBrowser.getEngine();
    eng.load("http://www.ghin.com/lookup.aspx");
}
```

If I can't fix this, I have to go back to my old dotnet program which was very unreliable.

Any ideas would be appreciated.
The first image is correct and the second is wrong.

[image: This is what the page should look like]

[image: This is what I am getting now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is with the website and not with JavaFX or the WebView because I get the exact wrong output if I just open your URL with Firefox or Chrome on my Mac.

Comment: That is strange. If I put the URL in Chrome on my windows 10, I get the correct output (the first image). My Note 8 phone with chrome renders correctly also. It only fails for me with WebView.

Comment: I just tried it again with Safari and the outcome is still the same.

Comment: Just to confirm, do you see image 1 or 2?

Comment: The second one with the white gap on all my three browsers on my MacbookPro Retina and MacOS 10.14.6.

Comment: I also just tried the URL with Chrome on my Samsung Android phone and there I do indeed see the correct image 1 version.

Comment: Thanks. maybe there is hope that the site will be fixed to work with all browsers.